Konva Polygon: Inaccurate getClientRect() for Move & Resize - Seeking Best Practices
I'm working with Konva to create and manipulate Polygons. I've noticed that using getClientRect() on a Polygon doesn't provide accurate coordinates for moving and resizing it.
<Group 
    draggable={true} 
    onDragMove={handleResizeMove}>
    <Line 
       points={points}
     />
</Group>

Ideally, getClientRect() would give me the top-left corner coordinates (x, y), width, and height of the Polygon's bounding box.
I've searched the Konva documentation and various forums but haven't found a clear solution.
How can I achieve accurate and reliable movement and resizing of Konva Polygons, considering the limitations of getClientRect() for this shape type? Alternatively, are there recommended methods or features in Konva to get the desired bounding box information for Polygons during move and resize operations?

Please make a demo. How do you see node.getClientRect() is not accurate?

Hi ,
I apologize for any confusion caused by my previous question. I was encountering inaccurate position calculations when using getClientRect().
After further investigation, I discovered that setting the relativeTo property within the configuration object provides a more accurate calculation.
Thanks
